# SQL table with lot of records how to select row with where clause against a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a SQL table with millions of records. I'm saving device tokens in this table. When I run a select query against this table and device token column which is string like `1d3b9b5ecd9dd9ddd4539555cee58395ggeeec61d42986ajjwd5394ddc34216cf84e898390dfdf19`

It consumes lot of memory and CPU. Is there any efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a query like this:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM TABLEWITHMILLIONSOFRECORDS T
WHERE DEVICETOKEN = '1d3b9b5ecd9dd9ddd4539555cee58395ggeeec61d42986ajjwd5394ddc34216cf84e898390dfdf19';
```

If so, you can improve performance by building an index on the `devicetoken` field:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_TABLEWITHMILLIONSOFRECORDS_DEVICETOKEN 
    ON TABLEWITHMILLIONSOFRECORDS(DEVICETOKEN);
```

This should speed your query.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I have already marked this column as a nonclustered index. But still the qurey is slow and uses a lot of server's resources.

Comment: @AbhinavMoudgil . . . What is the type of the column?  One possibility is that the types are not compatible.  Even something as small as a difference in collation can prevent the use of the index.

Comment: The type is varchar(500). Is this what you are asking?